# Broadcast link vs. point-to-point links

Tags: ethernet, subnet, network, network-theory

What is the distinction between broadcast links and point-to-point links? In the paragraph below, the author switches between "broadcast link" and "broadcast network" which is causing my confusion..is there a distinction between a "broadcast network" and a "broadcast link"? The word 'link' to me implies a physical link.

Does a broadcast network consist of point-to-point links?

Can a network be made of up of point-to-point links and broadcast links?

> **Broadly speaking, there are two types of transmission technology that are in widespread use: broadcast links and point-to-point links.**
>   Point-to-point links connect individual pairs of machines. To go from the source to the destination on a network made up of point-to-point links, short mes- sages, called packets in certain contexts, may have to first visit one or more inter- mediate machines. Often multiple routes, of different lengths, are possible, so finding good ones is important in point-to-point networks. Point-to-point transmission with exactly one sender and exactly one receiver is sometimes called unicasting.
>
> In contrast, on a broadcast network, the communication channel is shared by all the machines on the network; packets sent by any machine are received by all the others.
>
> -- From, Computer Networks - A. Tanenbaum

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tanenbaum is referring to a rather theoretical and somewhat narrow view of a network. In that, each connection (link) can be either point-to-point (p2p) or broadcast (p2mp).

A p2p link can only connect two nodes - think of a simple serial line. A packet sent by a node is only received by the node at the other end. Addressing is an option but not necessarily required.

With a broadcast link, more than two nodes can be connected - either by all sharing a single wire (shared medium) or with some kind of concentrator (hub) in between. This is also called point-to-multipoint (p2mp). That way, a packet sent by a node is received by *all* other nodes. Obviously, there must be some kind of addressing but that may happen at a higher network layer.

In real life, it helps to look at a specific technology. The ubiquitous Ethernet started out as a broadcast network in the physical layer (10BASE5 and 10BASE2) - a shared electric wire is tapped into by all nodes (bus topology), and a packet sent by any node was received by all the other nodes. Each packet has a destination address and packets not addressed to the receiver were simply ignored.

Because shared media can become a pain when troubleshooting and to leverage existing twisted-pair cabling, that shared wire was replaced by a repeater hub and all taps were replaced by electric p2p links (10BASE-T). The hub took care that on the handling side (upper physical layer) nothing changed but the electric topology (lower physical layer) changed from bus to star.

A simple broadcast network ("collision domain") can only transport *a single packet at any given time*, regardless of its size - that doesn't scale well. Larger networks were split by bridges or consequently by switches. Those split up the shared collision domain into one on each port and *selectively forward* between them by destination address. That way, many packets (frames) can run through a network simultaneously. Here, each link  represents a p2p connection at the full physical layer (L1). However, addressing is still used throughout, so at the data link layer (L2) the network is still a kind of broadcast network (a selective one though).

> Does a broadcast network consist of point-to-point links?

It may but not necessarily though (e.g. 10BASE5 or Wi-Fi).

> Can a network be made of up of point-to-point links and broadcast links?

Yes - at least with "network" as a higher-layer term. An IP network (L3) can use a wide variety of links further down. Even an Ethernet network can use a mix of p2p and p2mp L1 links (e.g. with 10BASE-T and 10BASE5 connected together).