# What really a point to point connection means?

Tags: router, network, networking, ppp, point-to-point

I know that point to point connection is used to directly connect between two nodes without any intermediate. But if we take in our world the internet(WAN) , let's say I want to achieve a point to point connection from a computer in India to computer in USA. How exactly is a point to point connection achieved in this case? . There is no direct fibre optic line connected between two computers. The connection has to be made through internet and it passes many routers to reach the destination. Then It contradicts the definition of point - to point as it involves routers inbetween and the connection is not direct.

Please explain what a point to point connection is and why we need a point to point protocol, Why can't we just pass the data as we normally would in an ethernet frame if the data passes all routers just like a normal connection in a point to point connection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Broadcast link vs. point-to-point links](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/60385/broadcast-link-vs-point-to-point-links) P2P links can be literal hardware connections or logical connections.

Comment: @Zac67 Thanks , that explain wat a point to point is. That means our entire network is made up of point to point right?. But I still don't know why a connection from a node in india and USA is called point to point and why a ppp protocol is used instead of normal ethernet frames. I still don't get it.

Comment: At the physical layer, modern Ethernet is entirely P2P, but at the data link layer it's a broadcast network/P2MP. Dedicated leased lines that connect exactly two nodes are also called P2P even though they might not be at the hardware level.

Comment: @Zac67 Thanks But I also want to know why ppp protocol is used for a point to point connection .

Comment: PPP creates a data-link-layer (L2) connection on top of a simple serial interface/byte stream - framing, link control/multiplexing for L3, and arbitration of L3 parameters (NCP).

Comment: @Zac67 Thanks for all your answers .They were really helpful for my understanding. I've searched over the internet and I got my understanding.